# Angular 4 PHP backend posting error

Tags: php, angular

Hi i got this error when i'm posting data to my backend, i'm using php and i already allow the header at the back end:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Please refer to the attached image below. Thanks

[image]

Comment: The message tells you in plain English what is missing.

Comment: but i already implemented the header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); in the back end.. when im using http.get there is no problem i encounter

Comment: _“but i already implemented the header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); in the back end”_ - that is very nice for you - but that is not the header the error message mentions.

Comment: so what does it mean?

Comment: Probably that you should go read up on how CORS works …? The request you are sending includes a `Content-Type` header - but for that to work, the remote party has to first of all signal that it is willing to accept such cross-domain requests that include this header. And that is what the header the message mentions is for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable cors in your php backend please refer to https://enable-cors.org/server_php.html

Comment: i already added the header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); in my backend

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys i got the answer i just added the following parameters in my post.  Here's the code:

```js
create(item){
      let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      
     return this.http.post("your_url_here.com/index.php",item,options)
    .map(data => data.json())
    .toPromise();
}
```